# ajax post request sending multiple request

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatables table that when clicked on I get a modal dialog with a dropdown list and a update tech button. When I click update tech the first time it works fine. But when I try more than once I get the previous request sent as well. In other words lets say I updated one activity for one tech, when I try to update another activity for another tech. It updates both the previous request and new one with the current tech.

```
    $("#dataTables-example").on('click', 'tr', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();                    
                var nTds = $('td', this);
                console.log(nTds);
                //example to show any cell data can be gathered, I used to get my ID from the first coumn in my final code
                var sBrowser = $(nTds[0]).text();
                var sGrade = $(nTds[4]).text();
                var dialogText="The info cell I need was in (col2) as:"+sBrowser+" and in (col5) as:"+sGrade+"" ;
                var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
                $.getJSON('/workorder/' + sBrowser, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var template = "<table class=table><thead><tr><th>Line</th><th>Product</th><th>Status<th>Price</th><th>Access</th><th>Serial</th><th>Callback</th><th>Delete</th></thead><tbody></tbody><tr></tr>{{#lines}}<td>{{Line #}}</td><td>{{Product}}</td><td>{{Status}}</td><td>{{price}}</td><td>{{accessCard}}</td><td>{{Serial #}}</td><td>{{callback}}</td><td><button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' type='button'>Delete</button></td><tr>{{/lines}}<tfoot><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Total</td><td></td><td></td></tfoot></table>";
                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

                $('.modal-body').html(html);
                $('#myModal').modal()
                $.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "PUT"};
                $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

                });
$('#updateTech').click(function() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/workorders/' + sBrowser,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'techId':$('#options').val(),'activityNumber':sBrowser}, // An object with the key 'submit' and value 'true;
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(sBrowser);
            console.log($('#options').val());
        }
    }); 
});
});
```

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a remove() method upon closing the modal so it goes away.

I'm not familiar with this Mustache code, but the idea is to add a close function to the modal so that it destroys the dom that was added.   The core issue is that you end up with 2 appends to the dom with options lists that make it into your post function to the DB.

so,

on close event, fire a function that empties the html

```
 $('.modal-body').html('');
```

exactly how to do that with this plugin I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Undinding the update button did the trick. `$('#closemodal').click(function() { 
$( "#updateTech").unbind( "click" );
});`